# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when changed to NodeJS Async Await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I recently learned about NodeJS Async/Await. Changed my codes to make it cleaner and easier to read.

- Upgraded to NodeJS 8.2.1.
- MongoDB 2.2.30
- Express 4.1.4

Code Looks like below:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var assert = require('assert');
    var url = process.env.mongo;


    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
      try{
        let db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
        let col = await db.collection('product');
        let documents = await col.find();
        return res.send(documents)
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }

    });


module.exports = router;
```

Having problem with this error,

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at stringify (/home/edmondtm/test-async/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1064:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/home/edmondtm/test-async/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:243:14)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/edmondtm/test-async/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:152:21)
at /home/edmondtm/test-async/routes/index.js:15:16
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Note: No problem if change:
let documents = await col.find(); to
let documents = await col.findOne();

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`let documents = await col.find().toArray()`

`col.find()` returns a cursor while `someCursor.toArray()` returns a promise.